# Generating Javascript random number into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need help with Javascript to generate number in HTML. I'm close but can't get it to quite work. Help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmPgR/251/

```js
function getNumber() {
    var minNumber = 0; // The minimum number you want
    var maxNumber = 100; // The maximum number you want
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number
    $('#myNumber').html(randomnumber); // Sets content of <div> to number
    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}

window.onload = getNumber; // Runs the function on click
document.getElementById("yourNumber").innerHTML = randomnumber;
```

```html
<div id="myNumber"></div>
<p id="yourNumber">
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `onload` works after the next statement, because it works asynchronously. And besides this, you use a `randomnumber` outside from it's scope, where it is not `accessible`.

So I suggest you to return the `randomnumber` from the function and use that function in the `onload` event handler. Inside that handler call your function, get the number and assign to your element's text.

And also if your `getNumer`'s logic is to return the number, don't assign anything inside it, just return the number. **It's responsibility is to return a random number**. Pass the range to it, don't hard code: in another place you can need a random number in the different range. Other logic implement outside of that function.

```js
function getRandomNumber(minRange, maxRange) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRange + 1) + minRange);
}

window.onload = function() {
    const rand = getRandomNumber(0, 100);
    document.getElementById("yourNumber").innerHTML = rand;
    $('#myNumber').html(rand);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myNumber"></div>
<p id="yourNumber"></p>
```

Comment: @Bylonb If this helps you, you accept it and help others to find it

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
function getNumber() {
    var minNumber = 0; // The minimum number you want
    var maxNumber = 100; // The maximum number you want
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number
    document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = randomnumber; // Sets content of <div> to number
    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}

window.onload = getNumber; // Runs the function on click
```

```html
<div id="myNumber"></div>
<p id="yourNumber">
</p>
```